# How to get file info in Python3 using os.listdir?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, stat

I simplified the problem. Now I have only this code:

```
files = os.listdir(dir_path)
print(files)

for f in files:
    info = os.stat(f)
    print(info.st_mtime)
```

Which gives me this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: anyfile.txt
```

And `print(files)` is returning the files which I want. Why can't I access to their properties?

Thank you in advance, I am a bit lost with this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution... I only had to change this line:

```
info = os.stat(dir_path + f)
```

What a waste of time! Sorry for my stupid question!

Comment: Happens to the bests of us! No worries! It might save time to someone else later, you never know!